# Visual Studio Code remote SSH into Proxmox CT container

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a Proxmox server where I have set up a debian CT container.

I can access the container fine from my local machine fine using SSH. I've added the SSH key so as not to require a password to access.

I'm now trying to access this server from VS Code using Remote-SSH. VS Code tries to connect forever without actually connecting.

What am I missing? And what are the steps to debug this?